# How to take Red pixel at image and transform Red pixel to probability transform and perform KL divergence at python

Tags: python

I am trying to extract red pixel at image and transform to probability density function to perform KL divergence at python

For the next i would like to perform with 2 image red pixel and calculate KL divergence

This is what i already do, sorry if noob and mess code

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
from numpy import linspace
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from scipy.stats import norm
import tensorflow as tf
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
from scipy.stats import entropy


 def getRed(redVal):
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (redVal, 0, 0)
def getGreen(greenVal):
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (0, greenVal, 0)
def getBlue(blueVal):
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (0, 0, blueVal)
# Create an Image with specific RGB value
image = Image.open("C:/Users/ahsan/Downloads/bunga/1.png")
# Modify the color of two pixels
image.putpixel((0,1), (1,1,5))
image.putpixel((0,2), (2,1,5))
# Display the image
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
# Get the color histogram of the image
histogram = image.histogram()
# Take only the Red counts
l1 = histogram[0:256]
# Take only the Blue counts
l2 = histogram[256:512]
# Take only the Green counts
l3 = histogram[512:768]
plt.figure(0)
# R histogram
for i in range(0, 256):
    plt.bar(i, l1[i], color = getRed(i), edgecolor=getRed(i), alpha=0.3)
plt.figure(3)

data = l1

kde = gaussian_kde( data )

dist_space = linspace( min(data), max(data), 100 )
# plot the results
plt.plot( dist_space, kde(dist_space) )

plt.show()

def kl(p, q):
    """Kullback-Leibler divergence D(P || Q) for discrete distributions
    Parameters
    ----------
    p, q : array-like, dtype=float, shape=n
    Discrete probability distributions.
    """
    p = np.asarray(p, dtype=np.float)
    q = np.asarray(q, dtype=np.float)

    return np.sum(np.where(p != 0, p * np.log(p / q), 0))
plt.plot(x, q, c='red')
p=l1 #Just example i will try with 2 image
q=l2 # Just ecample would like to try with 2 image
assert entropy(p, q) == kl(p, q)
```

But i am still can't calculate the KL divergence